# Inline script at the top executes after all the iframes on page have loaded

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I have this code inlined in my webpage near the top:

```
console.log('Script executed');
```

This is the only line inside the script tag. The page also loads 5 different iframes. I want the script to execute as soon as possible but it seems like it does not execute until all the iframes have loaded. Aren't scripts supposed to be executed as soon as the browser encounters them? Am I missing something?

This is my page structure:

```
<head>
  All Meta Tags. Stylesheet Links.
</head>
<body>
  Some HTML code.
  <iframe>1 iframe</iframe>
  More HTML.
  <script>console.log('Script Executed');</script>
  More HTML.
  <iframe>4 iframes</iframe>
  More HTML.
</body>
```

Comment: Show the relevant bits of code please, e.g. your page structure and how you embed the script and iframes.

Comment: Where is your <script> tag? In the <head> or in the <body>?

Comment: @mklimek It is in the body.

Comment: @Timo I am updating the question to show how the page is structured. :)

Comment: you just need to move the script to the head and it will execute first

Comment: @rule I want it to execute after a certain button has been loaded into the DOM and I have put the script right after that button.

Comment: does it really work without closing the script?

Comment: @rule I forgot to add it in the question. :D

Answer (score 0):

If you move your `<script></script>` to `head` section it will be executed as soon browser encountered it.

Everything which is in `body` will wait until document will be fully loaded  (and `onload` event gets fired).